# How to send raw packets

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-c++, c#-4.0, network-programming, windows-phone-7.1.1

I am unable to send raw packets from windows phone to remote client.

also there is no enum value in `SocketType` enumeration for raw packets.

But still i can see many applications in windows phone marketplace, that can send and recieve raw packet . eg. ICMP packets

Can somebody tell me how i can do this in C#, or if i need to write a c++ dll and then perform P/Invoke?

Answer (score 1):

Windows phone is based on Windows Embedded compact, formerly known as Windows CE.

While I worked with Windows CE it didn't support raw sockets. To send raw packets you need a protocol driver. If you are reluctant to write your own protocol driver, you can try [NDISUIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms892535.aspx). It's a protocol driver with an additional stream driver interface. When some ioctl calls you can instruct it to send (and receive) raw packets.

Windows phone 7 is based on Windows CE 6.0, but I think the NDISUIO could also be available here.